# JavaScript Redirect Prevents CSS Overlay on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, css

I'm building a PayPal Express Checkout page; unfortunately PayPal takes so long to load on redirect that I've been forced to design a page overlay to display for those several seconds. The sequence works on FF and Chrome, but alas IE chokes on it.

FYI: When I call SetOverlay() first, the redirect never happens--on any browser. Odd. So naturally I swapped it over to redirect before setting the overlay.

All I get on IE is disabled buttons, nothing more. If I comment out the redirect, the overlay displays as expected.

Does anyone have any ideas or know of a hack to get this to work on IE? Thanks.

Here's the server-side code:

```
sOverlay = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/Overlay.js"))

Me.Page.Header.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<script src=""Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js""></script>"))
Me.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType, "Overlay", sOverlay, True)
Me.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "Redirect", "window.location.replace('{0}');".ToFormat(.GetRedirectUrl(sToken)), True)
Me.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "SetOverlay", "SetOverlay();", True)
```

And then the client-side code:

```
$(function SetOverlay() {
  var docHeight = $(document).height();

  $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");
  $("body").append("<div class='heavy blue' id='box'>Transferring to PayPal...</div>");

  $("#overlay")
    .height(docHeight)
    .css({
      'background-color': 'black',
      'position': 'absolute',
      'opacity': 0.3,
      'z-index': 4999,
      'cursor': 'wait',
      'width': '100%',
      'left': 0,
      'top': 0
    });

  $("#box")
    .css({
      'background-color': 'white',
      'text-align': 'center',
      'margin-left': '-150px',
      'position': 'absolute',
      'padding': '20px',
      'z-index': 5000,
      'border': 'solid 1px #4088b8',
      'cursor': 'wait',
      'width': '300px',
      'left': '50%',
      'top': '40%',
      'box-shadow': '0 0 4px 2px gray'
    })
});
```

Comment: Might have something to do with the event queue blocking. Could your try wrapping your redirect in timeout: `setTimeout(function() {window.location.replace('{0}');}, 50)`

Comment: Funny thing, that. On a hunch, I was just about to try this exactly. But then I thought of what turned out to be the answer: skip JQuery and use POCSS instead. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the trick. I ended up skipping JQuery altogether and going with a pure CSS solution.

Works great. (Wanted to leave the question alive in case anyone else hits the same bump.)

Here's the code.

.ASCX:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlOverlay" runat="server" Visible="False" CssClass="Overlay"></asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlCaption" runat="server" Visible="False" CssClass="heavy blue Caption">Transferring to PayPal...</asp:Panel>
```

Code Behind:

```
Me.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "Redirect", "window.location.replace('{0}');".ToFormat(.GetRedirectUrl(sToken)), True)
Me.Page.Header.Controls.Add(New Controls.Styler("Overlay"))

pnlOverlay.Visible = True
pnlCaption.Visible = True
```

CSS:

```
div.Overlay {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: 4999;
  cursor: wait;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

div.Caption {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -150px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 5000;
  border: solid 1px #4088b8;
  cursor: wait;
  width: 300px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 40%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px gray;
}
```

Styler Class:

```
Public Class Styler
  Inherits LiteralControl

  Public Sub New(FileName As String)
    Dim _
      sFileName,
      sStyles As String

    sFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName)
    sStyles = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Styles/{0}.css".ToFormat(sFileName)))

    Me.Text = "{0}<style type=""text/css"">{0}{1}</style>{0}".ToFormat(vbCrLf, sStyles)
  End Sub
End Class
```